# Most expensive magic item at caster levels 3 through to 6 in 3.5e's Core?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

In a game using 3.5e's Core books exclusively, what is the most expensive magic item available at each of the caster levels 3, 4, 5 and 6?

I want to make money making magic items, so I want to know where to put my followers.

Comment: I believe you are suffering a bit of a misconception: the CL of a magic item is not one of its prerequisites, and therefore isn't actually relevant to considerations of what to use your Leadership to break the economy with. (Also, obligatory "please make sure your DM is OK with this sort of money-mill stunt".)

Comment: page 215 DMG: "For other magic items, the caster level is determined by the item itself. In this case, the creator's caster level must be as high as the items caster level(and prerequisites may effectively put a higher minimum on caster level).

Comment: Check errata, which removed that.

Comment: what is errata? I am using core only

Comment: WotC publishes corrections to their books (including Core) for free in the form of [errata](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata). These are always intended to be applied to the rules, and they're basically fixing errors in the original printings, so they take precedence. Or, you can check the [Hypertext SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/) which already has all the errata applied.

Comment: @user23625 It sounds like your group isn't using the errata. Which is fine; Plenty of games are run like that, and it cuts down on the number of rules sources you need to have at the table. That said, you might want to check with your GM about it, just in case errata is being used but you didn't realise.

Comment: I've edited this to go from "what is this for caster level 3, and maybe also up to 6," to just outright ask for all four of those levels. The beset answer will need to answer for all four anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't make money by making magic items.** Not in core, at least, and you did mention you were limited to the core: The cost of producing a magic item is half of the item's base price (or possibly a little more), while the money a player character can gain by selling a magic item is *also* half of the item's base price. This means that the amount you make by selling a magic item is at best the amount you spent to create it... Which is to say, you'd make as much profit as if you'd spent the same amount of time lazing around.

Even if that isn't the case (possibly because your GM is allowing you to make a slightly better profit margin), **there's no need to look up what the most expensive magic item is**; you just need to find one whose price is a multiple of 1000 gp. The time to craft a magic item, you see, is one day per 1,000 gp of market price or part thereof[1] - which means that as long as you're crafting magic items that are worth a multiple of 1,000 gp, it doesn't matter whether the items are worth 1,000 or 9,000 gp each - As long as you can find a buyer, you'll always make the same amount of profit per day. (Magic arms and armour are typically priced as multiples of a thousand, but because you have to buy the masterwork items to enchant and only get half of that money back when you sell the enchanted item, you actually lose money by enchanting them instead of breaking even.)

You should probably talk to your GM about this. If your GM agrees with me, you'll need to talk to them about how not being able to craft profitably affects your character; If your GM has some sort of house rules that change the game from what I've said above, you'll need to tell us those before we can give you a useful answer.

[1] There's actually one exception to the one-day-per-thousand-gp in the core rules: Potions always take exactly one eight-hour day to craft. Assuming your group allows a magic item to be made with caster level greater than that of its creator (this option was not originally in the core rules but was added in the errata) your followers will be able to churn out potions of any caster level they choose - allowing them to make potions of arbitrarily high value in a single day. (They still won't be able to sell them for more than their also-increased crafting cost, though.) If, on the other hand, the maximum caster level of a magic item is constrained to that of the creator, this will be less useful; Under such a system, a 6th-level caster can create potions worth no more than 900 gp each[2].

[2] Well, technically a potion that mimics a spell with an expensive material component could be worth more than 900 gp. However, that expensive material component has to be provided when brewing the potion, so the benefit is entirely eaten up by the increased cost.

Comment: Our house rules say you can sell it for 3/4 of the base price if you make it yourself for the purposes of making money.

Comment: Does your house rule also change the time required to craft said item? If it doesn't, it's one day per 1,000 gp. I don't know about you, but taking a couple of months off to craft a powerful magical sword is less profitable than adventuring, retrieving and selling said items for profit instead. If you've houseruled that players only take a day to craft their items, then this doesn't apply.

Comment: @user23625 That house rule is a rather vital detail; You should consider editing it into your question. If you do, I suspect someone will then provide an excellent reference to a magic item that's exactly 1000 gp, requires no unusual prerequisites, and could plausibly be sold in large quantities without disturbing the local economy. Provided that's something you want, of course.

Answer (score 1):

## This isn't how to make money

1) Magic Items sell-- at best-- for what it costs you to make them.  So you make nothing out of this if you produce and sell magic items normally

2) Potions, unlike other items, can be produced with a much higher rate of wealth production than 1000 gp/day.  Potions-- even maximally expensive potions-- are also among the cheapest magic items in the game.  So in terms of produced value in gp, potions make the most sense, assuming you can get past point # 1.

3) Maximally expensive items (none of which in your case are potions) take much, much longer to make than items costing only a few thousand gp.  Because of how economics works, this translates into being a worse investment than an item with the same gp/day rate of production but a higher turnover rate, though this is moot if you don't have a way of bypassing points #'s 1 and 2.

4) Actually dealing with your magic items often provides you more value than the cost of purchasing it.  Selling these items 'normally', then, even if you acquired them for free and could sell them at whole price, would be a waste of money.  The classic example of this, available at 9th level, is the [Robe of Useful Items](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Robe_of_Useful_Items), which costs 3500 gp to make and can be crafted to contain 16000 gp of real, non-magical gems.  Selling the cloak for 7000 gp profit, even if you could do so, would be over 5000 gp in losses when compared to what you should be getting.

5) your caster level doesn't restrict the items you can make, except inasmuch as you lack the spells you need to craft things or are making magic arms and armor.  This means that the most expensive item you can craft is simply the most expensive item in the game that isn't on an open-ended scale with Caster Lever and can be crafted with feats available at levels 3-6.  That item is the [Mirror of Life Trapping](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Mirror_of_Life_Trapping)

Comment: Point 5 is correct if playing with errata or with more recent prints of the core books; Otherwise, caster level may indeed be a limit.